# Unable to Call Table-Valued Function

Tags: sql-server, function

I have this function (MS SQL Server):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.activeEmpGivenCity(@city nvarchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT Emp_First_Name
    FROM Employee_Details AS e
    INNER JOIN City AS c ON e.Emp_City_Id = c.City_Id 
    WHERE @city = City_Name AND Emp_Active = 1
);
```

I am calling the function as such:

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[activeEmpGivenCity]('a');
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 223
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate     
"dbo.activeEmpGivenCity", or the name is ambiguous.
```

Also, when I hover my mouse over the function call it says:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.activeEmpGivenCity'.
```

I know the function exists, it is clearly in my database.

I've looked on this site: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2014/03/user-defined-functions-in-sql-server_20.html

And am calling the table-valued function exactly the way he/she is doing it.
What is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry guys, for some reason it is working now.

Comment: Glad that you have fixed by yourself, maybe you can post your answer here, or just delete this post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to call your function in other database

Change your function as below:

**Note:** Execute below function in relative database

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.activeEmpGivenCity(@city nvarchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT e.Emp_First_Name
    FROM Employee_Details AS e
    INNER JOIN City AS c ON e.Emp_City_Id = c.City_Id 
    WHERE @city = c.City_Name AND e.Emp_Active = 1
);
```

Comment: Clearly `Alias` name is not the problem here.